# "object = this" in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm familiar with the 'this' keyword used in java, it is used to reference the current object. The following piece of code shows how a node of a LinkedList is created:

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) { 
        data = d;
    } 


    void appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next; 
        } 
        n.next = end;
    }
}
```

But here I'm not sure what the following line in the above code states:

```
Node n = this;
```

I'm pretty sure that 'this' here is referenced to the current object, but is this object head, tail or any other node in the LinkedList? Not sure if my question makes perfect sense, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Node n` declares a variable named `n`, of type `Node`. `= this` initializes the variable `n` with `this`, which is also of type `Node`. So, after this instruction, `n` and `this` are two references to the same object. head and tail are irrelevant. And I can't understand what "is the head or any node in the LinkedList?" means.

Comment: @JBNizet , just corrected the typo. What I mean is are we referencing to head by 'this' keyword or is it just a reference to a node in general?

Comment: `n` will have the same value as the class (instance) when `appendToTail` is called. In this case, it's done so the `while` loop can execute on the current instance. This is no different than any other class.

Comment: If you call appendToTail() on the head, this will be the head. If you call it on the tail, this will be the tail. If you call it on a middle node, this will be that middle node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the `appendToTail(int d)` method appends the newly created node to the end of the list regardless of which Node its called from.

What happens is that one must find the end of the list in order to append the new Node to the end of it. Since we know that the node it is called from is in the list, it's an ideal starting point. Hence we choose the starting point as "this" node. But, this node is not necessarily the end of the list (in fact, it can be anywhere in the list), so we store it in a temporary variable `Node n = this` and continue changing our temporary variable until its the last node in the list, to which the new node can be added.

It's equivalent to starting from a random point (this) in a list and moving from that point to the end, wherever that is.

Hope this answered your question.

Comment: thanks @Theo, the way you explained is great to understand for a beginner like me.

Comment: @Aiguo It's a pleasure :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm pretty sure that 'this' here is referenced to the current object

Yup.

> but is this object head, tail or any other node in the LinkedList?

That depends where the method was called from or if the list contains `this` Node at all.

All the method does is assign a temporary reference to the current Node so it can be iterated over. You can't say which Node it is without more information.

---

From comments - *If you call appendToTail() on the head, this will be the head. If you call it on the tail, this will be the tail. If you call it on a middle node, this will be that middle node.*